# trigger on case feedItem when a chatter post is going on case it also receive by case team members

Tags: trigger, case, feeditem, chatter-feed

my  need is that any time any chatter post is going on case Case Team Members should also receive it.
 i am using entity subscription for it?
Basically here i want to do whenever some one insert a case feed on chatter or edit the chatter feed on case than the chatter post should also receive to the case team members, for this i am using entity subscription.
but i am not sure that it will work.
how to do it?
my code is As below:-

```
    public class CaseFeedTriggerHelper {
    public static List<FeedItem> newCasesFeed = new List<FeedItem>();
    public static List<FeedItem> oldCasesFeed = new List<FeedItem>();
    public static Map<Id, FeedItem> newMapCasesFeed = new Map<Id, FeedItem>();
    public static Map<Id, FeedItem> oldMapCasesFeed = new Map<Id, FeedItem>(); 

    public static void AlertToCaseTeamMembers(){
         Set<id> caseIds = new Set<id>();
        for(FeedItem fi : newCasesFeed ){
            if(fi.ParentId != null && String.valueOf(fi.ParentId).startsWith('500')){

                caseIds.add(fi.ParentId);
            }
        }
        Map<Id,Id> caseIdToCaseMemberId = new Map<Id,Id>();
        List<CaseTeamMember> listctm = new List<CaseTeamMember>();
       List<EntitySubscription> listEntitySub = new List<EntitySubscription>();

        for(CaseTeamMember ctm : [select id,ParentId
                                  from CaseTeamMember 
                                  where Parentid IN :caseIds
                                 ]){
            caseIdToCaseMemberId.put(ctm.ParentId,ctm.Id);
        }
        for(id caseId :caseIdToCaseMemberId.keyset()){
          EntitySubscription entitySub = new EntitySubscription();
            entitySub.ParentId = caseId;
            entitySub.Id = caseIdToCaseMemberId.get(caseId);
                   listEntitySub.add(entitySub);

        }
            insert listEntitySub;

    }

}
```

i am little bit suspicious about this code.
can anyone help me ,i am suspicious about loop and all
how to do it?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you suspicious? What works? What does not work, and exactly what does it do or not do? Do you see a specific error, and if so, what error on which line?

Could you edit your question to be more specific? See [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for more.

Comment: i dont think it will give me result which i want. it doesnt give me neither  error nor the result

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me as though the problem is with this section of code:

```
for(CaseTeamMember ctm : [select id,ParentId
                                  from CaseTeamMember 
                                  where Parentid IN :caseIds])
     {
      caseIdToCaseMemberId.put(ctm.ParentId,ctm.Id);
}
```

You're trying to create a SOQL for loop using the query above. Unfortunately, based on the Object Reference for [CaseTeamMember](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_caseteammember.htm), it appears to me the query isn't valid for what you're looking for: `MemberId` (UserId for a team member).

If the correct syntax were similar to what's written, it would require the query to only return one `MemberId` for each `caseId` (Limit 1). Otherwise, the query would return a `list<MemberId>` for all members of the team related to the Case. You'd need to sort that list before processing your results further.

The simplest solution would be to write the query correctly and not do it inside a SOQL for loop. You should then be able to perform a separate loop to create the map you need.